# Emissão de NF-e 4.0: Goiás (C#/.Net)

Tags: c#, nfe

Estou fazendo a atualização da comunicação da NF-e para alguns clientes e de maneira geral não estou tendo problemas para autorizadores como Rio Grande do Sul e São Paulo, por exemplo.

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer Goiás funcionar de maneira nenhuma.

A saber, eu fiz um Console Application simples, no qual inseri uma service reference para o serviço de Autorização de NFe de Goiás (requer certificado digital):

https://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeAutorizacao4?wsdl

O erro acontece sempre que chamo o método remoto "nfeAutorizacao": System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: 'Não foi possível estabelecer um canal seguro para SSL/TLS com autoridade 'homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br'.'

A saber: a cadeia de certificados está devidamente instalada.

[image: Cadeia de certificados]

Uma coisa que eu achei estranha é que, apesar do wsdl estar em um HTTPS, o endpoint resolvido pelo serviço é http.

```
<client>
   <endpoint address="http://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br:80/nfe/services/NFeAutorizacao4"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NFeAutorizacao4ServiceBinding"
            contract="Hom.Goias.NFeAutorizacao4Service" name="NFeAutorizacao4Port" />
</client>
```

Se eu forço https, meu erro é de timeout.

O meu código segue abaixo:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var client = new Hom.Goias.NFeAutorizacao4ServiceClient();


        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate =
            new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(@"D:\Projects\XPTO\CERT.pfx", "SENHADOCERTIFICADO");


        var xdoc = new XmlDocument();

        xdoc.Load(@"d:\Projects\XPTO\nfe-go.xml");

        var resp = client.nfeAutorizacaoLote(xdoc);

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
```

Qualquer sugestão é bem vinda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui!

No final foi mais uma questão de ajustar os bindings mesmo!

Quando mudo o endereço para "https" eu preciso tirar a porta 80. Além disso, tive que acrescentar algumas informações sobre o transporte. Mas no final, funcionou!

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="NFeAutorizacao4ServiceBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Digest" requireClientCertificate="true"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeAutorizacao4"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NFeAutorizacao4ServiceBinding"
          contract="Hom.Goias.NFeAutorizacao4Service" name="NFeAutorizacao4Port" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```